# preselected and presorted pivot tables

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with 16 columns.

I want to make a pivot table on presorted and preselected cells.

For example, the spreadsheet must be filtered when creating and be able to unfiltered without affecting the data.

The preselected cells would be columns A, C, F, H, and J.

Help would be truly appreciated!